# Using CASE WHEN to fetch value based on another column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that contains data in the following format,

| Date | Metric_Type | Metric_Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | v1 | 1.5 |
| 01/01/2021 | v1.2 | 7.2 |
| 01/01/2021 | v1.3 | 1.85 |

NOTE: The different versions of the metric type represent updates to the metric during each quarter.

I want my query to lookup the metric value pertaining to a specific metric type depending upon the quarter in which the date falls on.
For example, if the date is 01/01/2021 - I want my query to pull metric_value pertaining to v1 (which references 1st quarter).

Here is a sample of the query I tried

```
SELECT date, CASE WHEN (QUARTER(DATE) = 1 AND metric_type = 'v1') THEN metric_value ELSE 0
FROM table
```

My output looked like this

| Date | Metric_Value |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 1.5 |
| 01/01/2021 | 0 |
| 01/01/2021 | 0 |

But the flaw in my logic is that it returns all three rows with only one row having the metric value that matches my case when condition. Ideally, I want my query to return only the first row as the result. Is there any way to accomplish this using SQL?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, instead of this:

```sql
SELECT date, CASE WHEN (QUARTER(DATE) = 1 AND metric_type = 'v1') THEN metric_value ELSE 0
FROM table
```

You want this:

```sql
SELECT date, metric_value
FROM table
WHERE (QUARTER(DATE) = 1 AND metric_type = 'v1')
```

I'm only confused because this is basic SQL, but it seems to be exactly what the question wants.

Comment: yes, the question feels like the larger problem has been simplified down, and this "filter" belongs on a JOIN ON clause, Where it would make more sense in as part of a bigger query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I’d like to call out that each date will have 4 version types and four corresponding metrics. My problem is that I’m not able to get metric corresponding to v1 for Q1, metric value corresponding to v1.2 for Q2,  metric value corresponding to v1.3 for Q3 and so on without getting duplicates for the date records. Solving this is the intention of my question.

Comment: Please add more examples to the question so we can understand the problem @kaushik

Answer (score 0):

If you have many rows, and you only want the "rows for the matching quarter"

Then you can do a WHERE with four clauses OR'ed together, or use a UNION. Myself I would go that latter route as, while the SQL is hard to read, it's easer for the engine to execute (that is if you are worried about performance).

Thus:

```
SELECT date, metric_value
FROM table
WHERE (
    (QUARTER(DATE) = 1 AND metric_type = 'v1') OR
    (QUARTER(DATE) = 2 AND metric_type = 'v1.2') OR
    (QUARTER(DATE) = 3 AND metric_type = 'v1.3') OR
    (QUARTER(DATE) = 4 AND metric_type = 'v1.4')
)
```

```
SELECT date, metric_value
FROM table
WHERE QUARTER(DATE) = 1 AND metric_type = 'v1' 
UNION ALL
SELECT date, metric_value
FROM table
WHERE QUARTER(DATE) = 2 AND metric_type = 'v1.2' 
UNION ALL
SELECT date, metric_value
FROM table
WHERE QUARTER(DATE) = 3 AND metric_type = 'v1.3' 
UNION ALL
SELECT date, metric_value
FROM table
WHERE QUARTER(DATE) = 4 AND metric_type = 'v1.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

use Row_Number() partition by Metric_Type and quarter

```
declare @tmp as table(Date date,    Metric_Type varchar(20),    Metric_Value numeric(14,2))
insert into @tmp
values
('01/01/2021'   ,'v1',  1.5)
,('01/02/2021'  ,'v1',  0.5)
,('05/01/2021'  ,'v1',  2.5)
,('05/02/2021'  ,'v1',  3.5)
,('01/01/2021'  ,'v1.2',    7.2)
,('01/01/2021'  ,'v1.3',    1.85)

select * 
from
(
select 
DatePart(Quarter,Date) Q
,Metric_Value
,Row_Number() over(partition by Metric_Type,DatePart(Quarter,Date) order by Metric_Type,DatePart(Quarter,Date)) as RowID
from @tmp
)x
where RowID=1
```

output

```
Q   Metric_Value    RowID
1   1.50    1
2   2.50    1
1   7.20    1
1   1.85    1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to to map quarter to the version and filter based on mapping that matched. This should do it

```
select date, metric
from t
qualify quarter(date)= row_number() over (partition by date order by version)
```